# Pass variable into subquery

Tags: mysql

I would like to extract all clients' offers from each project and, in case they have more than one offer, I would like the average value.

I have the following query:

```
SELECT
@projectid := projects.id AS projectid,
(SELECT
  SUM(`offers`) FROM
  (SELECT AVG( `price` ) AS `offers`
    FROM `sales`
    WHERE `sales`.`projectid` = @projectid
    AND `sales`.`active` = 'yes'
    GROUP BY `sales`.`clientid`
  ) AS `average`
) AS `outstanding`
FROM projects
WHERE
projects.active = 'yes'
ORDER BY outstanding ASC
```

My problem is that @projectid is **not** passed into the subquery, and I don't understand how I should solve this issue.

Can anyone please give me some advices?

Comment: I haven't poured over your entire query, but why not just use `projects.id` in the subquery instead of the `@projectid` variable?

Comment: Since this is a rather complex query, you should provide a (test) schema in http://sqlfiddle.com/ and clearly show in your question what is the expected output of the query for the test schema.

Comment: I don't know if it's because it runs the sub-query before the rest of the query, but when I try with projects.id it only returns **#1054 - Unknown column 'project.id' in 'where clause'**

Comment: Yes. you have to have a projectid column in your inner queries. Please show the other tables definition. otherwise is more complicated.

Comment: @FredrikSetterqvist Judging by your query, it should be projectS.id, not project.id. The missing 's' would result in the error you describe.

Comment: @AaronMiller Sorry, my bad projects.id is also returning the error above.

Comment: @SylvainLeroux http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/19d0f/3

Answer (score 0):

Remember that SQL is a declarative language, not an imperative one. Many problem could be solved by using [`JOIN`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_%28SQL%29) and subqueries without "variables". So...

... I'm not very sure to understand -- but is you just need "for each project to sum of average offers by each client", something like that will do the trick:

```
SELECT S.projectid, SUM(offers) FROM
  (
    SELECT projectid, clientid, AVG(price) as offers FROM sales WHERE active = 'yes'
    GROUP BY projectid, clientid
  ) AS S 
JOIN projects on S.projectid = projects.id
AND projects.active = "yes"
GROUP BY projectid
```

See http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/19d0f/24

Comment: No, I'm afraid this wont work since the projects doesn't group in the output. I only want 1 line per project

Comment: I got it, maybe. You want "the average *total* offers for each project?

Comment: Yes, but it should only use the average if a client has more than one offer. In the example submited it would be 15000 on both project 1 and project 2.  

A fictive example could be that Project 1 has 4 sales from 3 clients. If Client A has an offer at 10000, Client B has 10000 and 2000, Client C 5000. Outstanding should say 21000.

Comment: @FredrikSetterqvist Thank you. That is much more clean now. I've modified my answer (and the [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/19d0f/24) link) based on your previous comment. At the very last, I reach the required 15000 :D

Comment: Thanks for your help but I'm afraid it's more complex, this is just a small part of a bigger query from the Projects table, so I think I'll need to stick with the basic syntax having projects in the last FROM-statment, but I will see if I can make it work anyway...